# Work done in force field

Tags: forces, work

I have a force $$\vec{F}=x^2 z \hat{i}+3y^3 \hat{j} +xz \hat{k}$$
which can readily be seen to be non-conservative.

I want to compute the work done moving a particle of unit mass from point $(1,0,\pi/4)$ to $(-1,0,-\pi/4)$ along the trajectory $\vec{r}=\frac{\pi}{4}x\hat{k}$

Now I'm very rusty on this stuff, but I'm having trouble following. Specifically, I don't see how this trajectory can possible take me between these points since it is only in the $\hat{k}$ direction, so how am I supposed to move from $x=1$ to $x=-1$?

Perhaps I'm also getting confused with the definition of points: does $(1,0,\pi/4)$ mean $x=1,y=0,z=\pi/4$ or are these values of the $\vec{r}$ vector?

Comment: @BowlOfRed Of course, that's not the issue - the issue is I can't see how such a trajectory can move me between those points

Comment: I think the real trajectory will be different from $\vec{r} = \frac{\pi}{4}x\hat{k}$. The path along which you are asked to calculate the work done is the projection of the real trajectory on the z-plane.